# Updating Seekbar after changing Edittext

Tags: java, android, seekbar

So I've got a seekbar and an edittext. My aim is to type in a number in the edittext, and in the same time the seekbar should jump to the related position. This should also work vise versa.

I've already got the code for them seperately. But something is missing. Because when I put in both and start then i can slide the seekbar and the value is changing in the same time in the edittext. But when i try to type in a number, it jumps to the beginning. Example: i want to type 123...result is 321. more or less the same with deleting. 
I think the two codes are crashing each other, bit i don't know what to change.

And maybe i should say that i'm new in this field.

I'm not sure if my intentions are understandable..

Here my codes:
1.

```
value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int after, int before, int count) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                try{
                    //Update Seekbar value after entering a number

                    int progress = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(s.toString()));
                    seekbar.setProgress(progress);
                    value.setText(value.getText().length());
                } catch(Exception ex) {}
            }

            });
```

2.

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {   
        value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As you see, there is a parameter passed into "onProgressChanged" function called "fromUser":

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
```

It defines that progress is changed by "physically" shfting the slider, so all You have to do, is just type as below:

```
if (fromUser) value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
```

It prevents doing this kind of loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
value.setText(value.getText().length());
```

This line is called first, changing the text.

```
value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
```

Then this line is called, changing the text to something else. These 2 `setText()`'s happen so fast, you cannot see that it happened twice, you only see the result of the last one.

I propose you remove the `value.setText(value.getText().length());`, displaying the length of the value string is not something you want to do, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `afterTextChanged()` method.

**1.** Remove line `value.setText(value.getText().length());` from `afterTextChanged()`.

```
value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int after, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            try {
                int progress = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(s.toString()));
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);

            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
```

**2.** Update `onProgressChanged()` method as below, to move `cursor` position as per `text` change.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
     value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
     value.setSelection(String.valueOf(progress).length());
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

`value.setText(value.getText().length());` is not using to display the length. It is used to place the cursor position at the end of edittext instead of going it to start position